# How to find out the best combination of a given vector whose sum is closest to a given number

Tags: r, algorithm

My question is quite similar to this one: [Find a subset from a set of integer whose sum is closest to a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717186/use-dynamic-programming-to-find-a-subset-of-numbers-whose-sum-is-closest-to-give)

It discussed the algorithm only, but I want to solve it with R. I'm quite new to R and tried to work out a solution, but I wonder whether there is a more efficient way.

Here is my example:

```
# Define a vector, to findout a subset whose sum is closest to the reference number 20. 
A <- c(2,5,6,3,7)

# display all the possible combinations
y1 <- combn(A,1)
y2 <- combn(A,2)
y3 <- combn(A,3)
y4 <- combn(A,4)
y5 <- combn(A,5)
Y <- list(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5)

# calculate the distance to the reference number of each combination
s1 <- abs(apply(y1,2,sum)-20)
s2 <- abs(apply(y2,2,sum)-20)
s3 <- abs(apply(y3,2,sum)-20)
s4 <- abs(apply(y4,2,sum)-20)
s5 <- abs(apply(y5,2,sum)-20)
S <- list(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5)

# find the minimum difference
M <- sapply(S,FUN=function(x) list(which.min(x),min(x)))
Mm <- which.min(as.numeric(M[2,]))

# return the right combination
data.frame(Y[Mm])[as.numeric(M[,Mm[1]])]
```

so the answer is 2,5,6,7.

How can I refine this program? Especially the five combn()s and five apply()s, is there a way that can work them at once? I hope when A has more items in it, I can use length(A) to cover it.

Comment: Try with `lapply(1:5, function(i) abs(colSums(combn(A, i))-20))`

Comment: I think the first 2 code sets can be replaced with `Y <- lapply(1:5, function(i) combn(A, i));
 S <- lapply(Y, function(x) abs(colSums(x) - 20))` and then apply your code

Comment: How big will your real `A` be?  For a large sized vector, your code will not finish in reasonable time since you are testing all combinations one by one.  If the length is 5 like in this example, there are only 32 combinations to check (32=2^5).   If the size is 20, then 1048576 combinations, which will end in a few minutes.  For 50, it is almost hopeless.  If you are working with a large size `A`, then you will need to find a clever algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way to do it,

```
l1 <- sapply(seq_along(A), function(i) combn(A, i))
l2 <- sapply(l1, function(i) abs(colSums(i) - 20))

Filter(length, Map(function(x, y)x[,y], l1, sapply(l2, function(i) i == Reduce(min, l2))))
#[[1]]
#[1] 2 5 6 7
```

The last line uses `Map` to index `l1` based on a logical list created by finding the minimum value from list `l2`.

Comment: Thank you! And your filter is much simpler than mine, really cool`

Answer (score 0):

`combiter` library has `isubsetv` iterator, which goes through all subset of a vector.  Combined with `foreach` simplifies the code.

```
library(combiter)
library(foreach)
A <- c(2,5,6,3,7)

res <- foreach(x = isubsetv(A), .combine = c) %do% sum(x)
absdif <- abs(res-20)
ind <- which(absdif==min(absdif))
as.list(isubsetv(A))[ind]
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing a new grammar to me! Dose "%do%" means multithread running? I didn't know it.

And you mentioned an alternative algorithm. My real A won't be larger than 20 items, but I'm still curious. Can you give me some implications?